# Why President's power to grant pardon to punishment or sentence are dealt separately in drafted language of article 72 of Constitution of India?

Tags: law, constitution, india

Constitution of India

Article 72 : **[Title: Power of President to grant pardons, etc., and to suspend, remit or commute sentences in certain cases]**

Sub Article (1) : The President shall have the power to grant pardons, reprieves, respites or remissions of punishment or to suspend, remit or commute the sentence of any person convicted of any offence....

I notice that adjectives

Pardons, Reprieves, Respites, Remission are used for change in 'Punishment'

But, suspend, remit, commute are used in case of 'Sentence'

What is the need to dissect given article between two scenarios, one for punishment and other for sentence, is there any material difference between two?

Comment: This really ought to be in Law.SE.

Comment: I didn't knew about Law.SE. Thank You so much. I'll ask there for sure, should i remove my question from here?

Comment: Seeing that you ha e a couple of anssers here, you may as well keep it. But do ask in Law.SE, you're more likely to get an expert answer.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing special, that's just how language (English) works.  Just like you "eat" bread, but "drink" water, you "grant a pardon", but you "suspend a sentence".  You don't pardon a sentence, you pardon a person. I suppose you could have phrased it differently, (eg grant a remission) - would that have made it clearer?

I suppose there is a minor ambiguity (again in the English) Does this give power to "grant a pardon",  or "grant a pardon of punishment"? But again context and normal English use allow us to understand this without difficulty.  The part "of punishment" only applies to "remission". Since the phrase "pardon of punishment" is not a normal colocation of words.  So we get, in bulleted form,

> The President shall have the power
>
> - to grant
> - - pardons,
> - - reprieves,
> - - respites
> - - or remissions of punishment
> - or to suspend [any sentence of any person convicted of any offence],
> - [to] remit [any sentence of any person convicted of any offence]
> - or [to] commute the sentence of any person convicted of any offence...

There's nothing sneaky here, just how English works.

Answer (score 3):

> Article 72 empowers the President the power to grant pardons, reprieves, respites or remissions of punishment or to suspend, remit or commute the sentence of any person convicted of any offence.

It's worth considering the legal context of each of these words: Pardon, reprieve, respite and remission on the one hand and suspend, remit and commute on the other. These are ordinary English words but they are also technical legal terms. They mean:

**Pardon**: It removes both the sentence and the conviction and completely absolves the convict from all sentences, punishments, and disqualifications.

**Reprieve**: It implies a stay of the execution of a sentence (especially that of death) for a temporary period. Its purpose is to enable the convict to have time to seek pardon or commutation from the President.

**Respite**: It denotes awarding a lesser sentence in place of one originally awarded due to some special fact, such as the physical disability of a convict or the pregnancy of a woman offender.

**Remission**: It implies reducing the period of the sentence without changing its character. For example, a sentence of rigorous imprisonment for five years may be remitted to rigorous imprisonment for one year.

And:

**suspend**: is a sentence that is deferred in order to allow the defendant to perform a period of probation. If the defendent does not break the terms of the probation or the law during his probation his sentence is considered fulfilled.

**remit**: to cancel or refrain from exacting a penalty.

**Commutation**: It denotes the substitution of one form of punishment with a lighter form of punishment. For example, a prison sentence may be replaced by a fine.

There is an implied distinction between the seriousness of the crime. Take for example the death penalty, which currently is a punishment for certain crimes under India's Penal Code. You generally reprieve someone penalised with the death penalty, you don't generally remit, suspend or commute this punishment. Likewise, a presidential pardon is generally used for serious crimes.

However, note there is no hard and fast rule here. A legal document is not a logic document. There will be all sorts of distinctions that a constitutional lawyer will be able to point out.